# unable to fit image grid in entire page

Tags: adjustbox, tabularray

I am positioning images as grid but i was unable to change the boarder spaces. I want to make the image sizes big and fit the entire page need help.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[demo,export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}



\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\adjustboxset{height=0.1\textheight,width=0.1\textheight,valign=c}

\caption{Something Descriptive for Method 1 and Method 2} % provide a suitable caption

\begin{tblr}{colspec={r cc r cc}, colsep=1pt, rowsep=1pt,
             vline{4}={0.5em,white},
              }
        & Method 1                & Residual   &
        & Method 2                & Residual            \\
Image 1 & \adjustimage{}{fig1a} & \adjustimage{}{fig1b} & Image 9
        & \adjustimage{}{fig1c} & \adjustimage{}{fig1d} \\
Image 2 & \adjustimage{}{fig2a} & \adjustimage{}{fig2b} & Image 10
        & \adjustimage{}{fig2c} & \adjustimage{}{fig2d} \\
Image 3 & \adjustimage{}{fig3a} & \adjustimage{}{fig3b} & Image 11
        & \adjustimage{}{fig3c} & \adjustimage{}{fig3d} \\
Image 4 & \adjustimage{}{fig4a} & \adjustimage{}{fig4b} & Image 12
        & \adjustimage{}{fig4c} & \adjustimage{}{fig4d} \\
Image 5 & \adjustimage{}{fig5a} & \adjustimage{}{fig5b} & Image 13
        & \adjustimage{}{fig5c} & \adjustimage{}{fig5d} \\
Image 6 & \adjustimage{}{fig6a} & \adjustimage{}{fig6b} & Image 14
        & \adjustimage{}{fig6c} & \adjustimage{}{fig6d} \\
Image 7 & \adjustimage{}{fig7a} & \adjustimage{}{fig7b} & Image 15
        & \adjustimage{}{fig7c} & \adjustimage{}{fig7d} \\
Image 8 & \adjustimage{}{fig8a} & \adjustimage{}{fig8b} & Image 16
        & \adjustimage{}{fig8c} & \adjustimage{}{fig8d} \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can alter width and height of the images by adjusting the corresponding values in the `\adjustboxset` command. Due to the number of images, you can't really make them much bigger than `height=0.114\textheight,width=0.114\textheight` without them overflowing into the margin.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't reproduce shoed image. Do you like to have inserted a column between images with their titles (Image 9 ... Image 16)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is not clear, what you mean with `entire page`
- your code doesn't reproduce showed image
- MWE for the case, that you are allowed to locally increase `\textwidth`, is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo,               % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep} % <---
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\adjustboxset{width=0.25\textwidth, valign=c}
\caption{Something Descriptive for Method 1 and Method 2} % provide a suitable caption
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[0.35,c,m] X[1,c]X[1,c] X[0.35,c,m] X[1,c]X[1,c]},
             colsep=2pt,    rowsep=2pt,
             leftsep=0pt,   rightsep=0pt,
              }
        & Method 1                & Residual
        & Method 2                & Residual            \\
Image 1 & \adjustimage{}{fig1a} & \adjustimage{}{fig1b}
        &   Image 9
        & \adjustimage{}{fig1c} & \adjustimage{}{fig1d} \\
Image 2 & \adjustimage{}{fig2a} & \adjustimage{}{fig2b}
        &   Image 10
        & \adjustimage{}{fig2c} & \adjustimage{}{fig2d} \\
Image 3 & \adjustimage{}{fig3a} & \adjustimage{}{fig3b}
        &   Image 11
        & \adjustimage{}{fig3c} & \adjustimage{}{fig3d} \\
Image 4 & \adjustimage{}{fig4a} & \adjustimage{}{fig4b}
        &   Image 12
        & \adjustimage{}{fig4c} & \adjustimage{}{fig4d} \\
Image 5 & \adjustimage{}{fig5a} & \adjustimage{}{fig5b}
        &   Image 13
        & \adjustimage{}{fig5c} & \adjustimage{}{fig5d} \\
Image 6 & \adjustimage{}{fig6a} & \adjustimage{}{fig6b}
        &   Image 14
        & \adjustimage{}{fig6c} & \adjustimage{}{fig6d} \\
Image 7 & \adjustimage{}{fig7a} & \adjustimage{}{fig7b}
        &   Image 15
        & \adjustimage{}{fig7c} & \adjustimage{}{fig7d} \\
Image 8 & \adjustimage{}{fig8a} & \adjustimage{}{fig8b}
        &   Image 16
        & \adjustimage{}{fig8c} & \adjustimage{}{fig8d} \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]